# Particle に to enumerate things / to list items?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

I encountered several sentences where に was used—from my deduction of the context—to enumerate things. For example a character about to go somewhere, checks his bag if he has everything he needs :
2:「忘れ物は？」
1:「大丈夫ー」
1:「－だと思うけど確認しておこう」
1:「**バンデージにタオルに**」
1:「**トランクス**」

I tried searching this grammar but couldn't satisfy my curiosity. Why and how に is used to enumerate things? I understand that it is basically used to tell the time, place, directions, cause, ect... But I'm lost on how to understand it used in that way.

Comment: See 中上級を教える人のための日本語文法ハンドブック, page 58.

Comment: @snailboat Thanks for your answer that's an interesting book, I'm self-taught and doesn't have knowledge on books that could help me now, I mostly rely on Japanese online dictionaries like Weblio.  
I found the answer after posting my question, in the Related articles "Differences between listing particles と, や, and に". The user "SomethingJapanese" posted a [link](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/166083/m0u/%E3%81%AB/) to the entry on Goo dictionary that did the job for me  (at the bottom of the page with the 4 on black field)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The parallel marker に is used when you're putting together a list of related things (nouns), adding each one as you go.  In particular, it gets used if you're *trying to think of things* (like when you're at a restaurant, trying to think of what food you want to get), and that includes when you're *trying to recall at least two things from memory* (like if you're trying to remember the names of a couple old friends).

I'm not a native speaker, so I won't try to make up my own examples.  I'll take a couple from the 日本語文法ハンドブック:

> 大根`に`にんじん`に`、えーと、それからトマトをもらおうかしら。

In this example, the speaker is trying to think of which food they'd like.  They list three: `大根`, `にんじん`, and `トマト`.  Note that the last item doesn't have `に`.  Also pay attention to the `えーと、それから` which helps give you the impression that the speaker is *trying to think of the items*--that's the sort of situation in which you tend to run across `に`.

Let's look at another example:

> イタリア旅行ではいろんな都市を訪ねたわ。ローマ`に`フィレンツェでしょ、それからミラノ`に`ヴェネツィアも行ったかしら。

Here again, the speaker is trying to call to mind a list of items.  In this case, there are two smaller lists, but they function as one larger list: `ローマ` and `フィレンツェ` form the first list, and then the speaker thinks of `ミラノ` and `ヴェネツィア` as well, adding them as a second list.  In each case, `に` is left off the end of the list.

Another example, this time from a video game (Gameboy Wars Advance 2):

> 「ほっほっほっ。マックス`に`イワン。
> また、ともに戦う事になってしもうたのう。」

The speaker remembers Max and Ewan from the first game, but he hasn't seen them in quite some time.  Because he used `に` to list the names, you get the sense that he's calling their names to mind from memory.  In this case, again the list only has two items, and again `に` is omitted from the last item in the list.

Comment: One of the easiest examples of this is to describe the structure of kanji.  例：込　→　しんにょう **に** はいる、見　→　め **に** ひとあし、持　→　てへん **に** てら.