# What is the difference between そして (soshite) and それから (sorekara)?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

Can anyone explain what is the difference between そして and それから, and when to use which?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is an article about the difference (although in Japanese):  [「そして」／「それから」の一考察](http://www.ffl.kanagawa-u.ac.jp/graduate/ronsyu/img/vol_04/vol04_04.pdf)

As shown in the picture below, in a nutshell, this article says that **それから involves a shift in viewpoint**, while そして adds information from the same viewpoint.

[image]

Let me try to explain this.

---

When you describe something happens after something, basically you can use both そして and それから. But それから more explicitly focuses on the sequence of events (what comes next to something), and often implies the two things happens more or less *independently*. It's closer to "after that" in English. On the other hand, そして often implies the second thing happens as a result of the first thing ("and" in English).

Examples:

> 今日【きょう】は宿題【しゅくだい】をして、｛そして／それから｝テレビを見【み】ます。
>   Today, I'll do my homework, ______ watch TV.

Here, そして and それから are interchangeable, but それから sounds more like "and after that" while そして sounds more like "and then".

> まじめに勉強【べんきょう】して、そして試験【しけん】に合格【ごうかく】しました。
>   I studied seriously, and passed the examination.

Here そして is the natural choice because he passed the exam *because* he studied seriously. Such reason-result relationships are denoted only by そして. If you used それから here, it would sound like "in addition", which sounds awkward.

> まず、まじめに勉強【べんきょう】して、それから試験【しけん】を受【う】けなさい。
>   You must study seriously first, and after that, take the exam.

Here それから is the natural choice because the speaker is strongly emphasizing the proper order of what you need to do. (Maybe you can forget the picture above in this case)

---

When you list multiple things, you can use both それから and そして:

> 彼【かれ】は日本語【にほんご】と英語【えいご】、｛そして／それから｝スペイン語【ご】が話【はな】せます。
>   He can speak Japanese, English, ______ Spanish.

Here そして and それから are interchangeable, but それから is much less common in formal, written, or organized sentences.

> 彼は日本語と英語が話せます。あ、それからスペイン語も。
>   He can speak Japanese and English. Oh, Spanish, too.

Here それから sounds more natural because the speaker was not "seeing" Spanish at first. In conversations, それから is a good word to add something as an afterthought (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12194/5010)).

> えーと、それから…
>   Um, let's see ... / And, well, er ...

Actually それから is a common filler word used when the speaker is trying to say something more. Maybe he's trying to "change his viewpoint".

Answer (score -2):

Used as a conjunction there is no difference.
They both can be translated as "and" or "then".
そして can also be used as an adverb meaning "in that way"

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/128664/meaning/m0u/
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/131765/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89/
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/43185/meaning/m0u/%E7%84%B6%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6/

Comment: Would you please expand a little bit your answer rather than giving raw links with a rough translation when the question is more about usage. I can understand that you want more rep because you need rep to perform some moderating task that may appeal to you. But, there is other ways to gain reputation rather than posting low quality answers. Indeed, you can edit other's posts to make them meet our standards. By doing so, you will be rewarded 2 points of rep each time one of your edit is accepted until you reach 2000 rep points.

Comment: The question is "what is the difference between そして and それから" and I have answered that part.
According to the dictionary, そうして and それから have identical definitions:
そうして: １ 前述の事柄を受け、それに継続して、あるいはその結果生じる事柄を導く。
２ 前述の内容を受けて、さらに付け加えることを表す。
それから: 前述の事柄に続いて、あとの事柄が起こることを表す。その次に。２ 前述の事柄に加えて、あとの事柄を示す。
So they are pretty much synonymous.

Comment: The second part is "when to use which". The problem is that it is a semantic question, and there is no correct answer for a semantic question.
It is like asking "when to use car and automobile".
According to the dictionary both "car" and "automobile" can be used as synonymous, but differente people will have different opinions about when to use which. There is no right answer about when to use which. It becomes a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: One last thing: the majority of people posting questions on this site are beginners, intermediate at most. So they are probably expecting a simple, easy-to-understand answer, not a treatise from a college professor. For a beginner it is enough to say that そうして and それから are synonymous, instead of delving into the nuances of each word, which will be too complicated for a beginner to understand.
An advanced learner is better off posting questions in Japanese for Japanese people at Japanese websites, not here.

Comment: `Used as a conjunction there is no difference.` -> If so, then why are they often not interchangeable? `An advanced learner is better off posting questions in Japanese for Japanese people at Japanese websites, not here. ` -> Huh?? Why shouldn't an advanced learner post questions here?? I don't think we have such a rule in this forum. And, even if the OP was a beginner, it doesn't mean you can post inaccurate answers.

Comment: `そして can also be used as an adverb meaning "in that way"` <- No. For "in that way", you use そうして, not そして.