# Soredewa versus Sorekara

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

Read the following please:

> ... このホテルはどちらもありません。**それから**、冷蔵庫もエアコンもありません。このホテルは便利ではありませんでしたが、山や湖で色々なことができました。

Can それでは be used in place of それから in the sentence above (both mean "then")?

By the way, wouldn't it be better to use それに instead? In that part of the passage they tell their readers what wasn't there in the hotel: "... There weren't either. *Moreover/besides*, there was neither a fridge nor an air conditioner..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this type of それから is not temporal "then". It is used to add another piece of information as an afterthought. In English, it's "(oh) and", "besides", or "in addition". It's not interchangeable with それでは that means "(and) then", but it's interchangeable with それに.

Related: [What is the difference between そして (soshite) and それから (sorekara)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40263/5010)

Comment: I'm not completely confident adding temporal is the best way to edit it. But there is at least one sense of "then" that doesn't mean anything about sequence and can be used to express afterhoughts.