# how to join negative sentence in japanese

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese, academic-japanese

Can I use soshite to join negative sentences in japanese? e.g. I am not a girl and he is not a boy. 私は女の子ではありません そして 彼は男の子ではありません。

Answer (score 4):

I believe **そして** it's used more in a sentence to show that the 2nd part of the sentence was done in result of the first (more like "then" in english): [soshite vs sorekara](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40264/16104)

I will list the 3 more common ways, I believe, of connecting negative sentences:

> **1 - て-form** - Found both in written and spoken form.
>
> 私{わたし}は女{おんな}の子{こ}じゃな**くて**、彼{かれ}は男{おとこ}じゃない。- I'm not a girl, and he is not a boy.
>
> **2 - く-form / stem form (?not sure what to call it)**  - More commonly found in texts/books.
>
> 私{わたし}は女{おんな}の子{こ}じゃな**く**、彼{かれ}は男{おとこ}じゃない。- I'm not a girl, and he is not a boy.
>
> **3 - て-form** (I guess this is just a complement of the first one, to be honest) - Used to correct a previous wrong assumption/statement.
>
> 私{わたし}は女{おんな}の子{こ}じゃな**くて**、男{おとこ}だよ。- I'm not a girl, I am a boy!!