# Use of に in a list of names?

Tags: particles, particle-に, anime

In this funny scene from the anime Kiniro Mosaic (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIauXFVABIQ), the character Karen is listing peoples' names to get familiar with them and says, "陽子、忍に、えっと…"

What is the reasoning behind the に after Shinobu's name? Wouldn't と make more sense? Karen is British, so did they insert that just to make her sound less fluent in Japanese?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12188/9831

Comment: @Chocolate Yes, you're completely right. I hadn't come across that post in my research, but that seems to be what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @charlieshades Not your fault. This site's search system is a joke unable to tokenize Japanese strings :)

Comment: Follow-up question: why is she using や to enumerate 綾{あや}? :)