# 「に」used to signify addition?

Tags: grammar, usage, particles

There are several instances where I noticed people use に to mean something along the lines of "and". Here's an example: https://youtu.be/3cjyUg-XjjU?t=24

I think the narrator says, "修理人が使う道具は、牛の皮、ハンマー**に**、庖丁と呼ばれる[刃も?].

Also, a line from a manga that describes a superhero reads、

```
その能力はスーパーパワーに
ビーム・バリアー
飛行能力に回復力
```

The に in question is the one in the third line.

I've searched all over the web for something that explains this usage, but I've found nothing. Does anyone what it is?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12188/particle-%E3%81%AB-to-enumerate-things This might help.

Comment: `...庖丁と呼ばれる[刃も?]` -- 「牛の革、ハンマーに、包丁と呼ばれる[刃物]{はもの}」ですね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

に can be used to enumerate things and be translated by "and".

Literally, it means "onto" (I think), so it feels like you're adding up something onto another thing.

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166083/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AB/

> ［並助］並列・列挙・添加・取り合わせを表す。「バターにチーズに牛乳」「月にむら雲、花に嵐」

It should be two words (or more) from the same semantic field. As you can see in the example sentences, the words are kinda related to each other.