# お仕事に学校頑張って meaning

Tags: particle-に

今日もお仕事に学校頑張って

What is 「仕事に学校頑張って」meaning

Is 仕事に学校 from 「仕事に学校へ行く」(Go to school to work) ?

Comment: Do you know who the speaker is? Is that housewife talking to her child and her husband at the same time? Or to single person?

Comment: The full sentence is 「おはよ〜☀︎*.｡

今日もお仕事に学校頑張って〜٩(｡•ω•｡)و」 It’s from an idol fanpage. They posted pics with this caption. Purpose is to give some motivation. I think.

Answer (score 15):

This に is [for listing things](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12188/5010) ("work *or* school"). The sentence is roughly the same as お仕事**や**学校**を**頑張って.