# Using に conjunctively to mean "In addition"

Tags: particle-に

I think this topic is also addressed [in this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12188/particle-%E3%81%AB-to-enumerate-things), but it doesn't address how に works outside of contexts where the speaker is trying to "*trying to think of/recall things*". I'd like someone to explain how に is used conjunctively in objective contexts. I've seen examples of sentences where に is used conjunctively when the speaker is narrating a story, which (I think) it wouldn't make sense to think that the narrator is "trying to remember" these nouns.

One example I found in a book I was reading is:

> そんなロレンスとホロが入った店は、小さな宿に併設の酒場だ。
>
>  The store that Lawrence and Holo entered was a small inn combined with a bar.

I think I might be reading this wrong, and the する after 併設 is just omitted in this sentence. In that case, I assume に is just marking the object of the する verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This に is not a conjunctive or listing particle, but is a particle used with 併設.

小さな宿に併設の酒場
= 小さな宿**に**併設されている酒場
= a bar attached **to** a small inn

We can say this because 店 can refer to a restaurant/bar/izakaya, but not to a hotel/inn. They entered a 酒場, not a 宿.