# An unexpected に

Tags: particles

From ノーゲーム・ノーライフ

Context: In the prologue, various urban legends are being listed

> ──『都市伝説』。
>
> 世に囁かれる星の数にも届くそれらは、一種の『願望』である。
>
> ──例えばそれは、『人類は月に行っていない』という都市伝説。
>
> ──例えばそれは、ドル紙幣に隠されたフリーメーソンの陰謀。
>
> ──例えばそれは、フィラデルフィア計画による時間移動実験。
>
> 千代田線核シェルター説、エリア51、ロズウェル事件**に**、エトセトラ──

ロズウェル事件に ends in に for some unexplicable reason. There's no verb to attach it to or anything. I tried googling it, but nothing came up. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this? [Particle に to enumerate things / to list items?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12188/particle-%e3%81%ab-to-enumerate-things-to-list-items)

Comment: @Shurim, thanks a lot. That seems to be exactly the case here.