# Help parse and understand the sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> メルセデス・ベンツ日本は、一部改良した「メルセデス AMG GT
> 4ドアクーペ」の日本導入を発表。予約受注を開始した。改良モデルでは、**従来のマルチチャンバーを備えたAMGライドコントロール+のエアサスペンションに、新たにダンパーの外側に2つの圧力制御バルブを上級モデルの「GT
> 53」に標準装備**。「GT 43」にはオプションで用意された。

How should I parse the bold part? Does it basically mean "to equip GT 53 with the pressure control valve as well as the air suspension"? The に immediately after エアサスペンション seems a bit tricky.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on why you're confused?

Comment: seems to me to be this に: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12188

Comment: You're confused for a good reason. Without knowledge of the configuration, one *may* interpret as either "the model has not only the air-sus, but **also** a new valve (to the outside of the damper)" or "we added a new valve **to the** air-sus!". They could've added 対して or 加えて or 更に etc. after サスペンションに. But of course it's not necessary for one who is car-savvy.

Comment: I wonder what's new in GT 43 if エアサスペンション is 従来 and 圧力制御バルブ is オプション.

Comment: As dungarian says, this seemed ambiguous at least to me. I would have needed to learn about the role of these parts first if I had had to answer this. It's nice to have someone who is good at cars.

Answer (score 2):

I think the sentence is simply bad, if not nonsense.

I suppose it parses as

- 従来のマルチチャンバーを備えたAMGライドコントロール+のエアサスペンション**に** (= **onto** AMGライドコントロール+のエアサスペンション equipped with マルチチャンバー, which was installed also in the previous model) - I assume 従来の modifies エアサスペンション.
- 新たにダンパーの外側に2つの圧力制御バルブを上級モデルの「GT 53」に標準装備 (what is new in this model, (they) equip the upper model with 2つの圧力制御バルブ on the outside of ダンバー
- （圧力制御バルブは）「GT 43」にはオプションで用意された　(The new valves are selectable as an option for the (lower model) GT43.)

I'm not familiar with fancy cars, so hopefully someone corrects me if I'm wrong.

The に here is *to* in meaning(possible expansion is に対して). Basically, it means *to the air-sus originally installed, they added new valves by default in GT53, and the valves are an option in GT43*.

---

The problem is that ...圧力制御バルブ*を* does not continue in the clause 「GT43」にはオプションで用意された. It should be オプションで**用意した** so that 圧力制御バルブ becomes the subject for both phrases (上級モデルの「GT 53」に標準装備 and 「GT 43」にはオプションで用意された) A possible rewrite is 新たにダンパーの外側に2つの圧力制御バルブ**が**上級モデルの「GT 53」**では**標準装備**された**。（圧力制御バルブは）「GT 43」にはオプションで用意された。

Comment: I personally think the valve was added **to** the suspension system. So, I think it's "サスペンションに**対して**バルブを新たに...". I **don't** think "サスペンションだけでなく、なんとバルブも新たに...". Because it makes sense for the suspension system to have dampers and hydro valves as components to improve the driver/passenger comfort. I may be wrong, but anyway the explanation in your answer is a good one assuming the に meant *and also*.

Comment: I found [this](https://www.motorshow.me/news-details/15091/meet-the-new-mercedes-amg-gt-4-door-coup/en) (emphasis mine): *The reconfigured AMG RIDE CONTROL+ suspension **continues to be based on** a multi-chamber air suspension system, **combined with** adaptive, electronically controlled adjustable damping. This damping system is completely new: for the first time, two so-called pressure limiting valves are used.* 従来 might be supposed to be modifying only マルチチャンバー and 圧力制御バルブ might have been added to AMGライドコントロール+のエアサスペンション, of which ダンパー are parts, after all.

Comment: Thanks. I edited accordingly.